# Calling results from methods outside main into variables in the main method

Tags: java, methods

My homework is to calculate taxes and surcharges for a jewelry store that is replenishing its stock, and I have run into a slight snag. I am using a method called calcExtraTax three times to calculate the labor rate and state and federal taxes. I then need to take the results of each instance of that method and pass the value into the appropriate variable in my main method. This is what my code looks like right now (evidently not complete):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

double stateRate = 0.1;
double luxuryRate = 0.2;
double laborRate = 0.05;
double extraCharge;
int numOrdered;
double diamondCost;
double settingCost;
double baseCost;
double totalCost;
double laborCost;
double stateTax;
double luxuryTax;
double finalAmountDue;

    Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the cost of the diamond?");
    diamondCost = keyInput.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the cost of the setting?");
    settingCost = keyInput.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("How many rings are you ordering?");
    numOrdered = keyInput.nextInt();

    baseCost = diamondCost + settingCost;
    calcExtraCost(baseCost, laborRate);
    laborCost = extraCharge;
    calcExtraCost(baseCost, stateRate);
    stateTax = extraCharge;
    calcExtraCost(baseCost, luxuryRate);
    luxuryTax = extraCharge;
    totalCost = baseCost + laborCost + stateTax + luxuryTax;
    finalAmountDue = numOrdered*totalCost;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The final amount due is = " + finalAmountDue);
}
public static void calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
{
    double extraCharge = diamond*rate;
    ???????????
}
```

what i'm trying to figure out is what else i need to put in my secondary method in order to be able to pass the result into a different tax cost variable each time depending on the rate variable used in the formula.

Comment: Do you know how to [`return` values from methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html), or have you only ever used `void` methods?

Comment: I have only ever used void methods.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: @James - I like how you got 2 upvotes for posting my same link 5 minutes later. :-p

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special with your `calcExtraCost` apart from changing the return type to double and returning the calculated value. For example

```
public static double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
{
    double extraCharge = diamond*rate;
    double tax = //some calculations
    return tax
}
```

So this method would return the calculated value.

In your main method you need to store that value to the appropriate double that you want. For example if you want to calculate the `luxuryTax`, then you do something like:

```
luxuryTax = calcExtraCost(baseCost, luxuryRate);
```

Also some advice, instead of making your method `static`, make it a `non-static` method, and create an object of the class where your method is defined, and call the method on that object.

For example if the class where you defined your method is called Tax, then you create an object of Tax:

```
Tax tax = new Tax();
```

and call `calcExtraCost` on that object:

```
tax.calcExtraCost();
```

This way you remove the static part of the method. So your method signature becomes like this:

```
public double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the value of `diamond*rate` from your helper method by changing its signature from `void` to `double` and adding a `return` statement:

```
public static double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
{
    return diamond * rate;
}
```

Now you can assign the result of a call to the variable in your main method:

```
laborCost = calcExtraCost(baseCost, laborRate);
```

Comment: so no calculation is necessary in the method? i can simply return the value without having to assign a variable to it first?

Comment: @Sai - Yes, you can return an intermediate expression—there's no need to assign it to a value first. If you were doing something more complex then it might be worthwhile to declare a new variable to hold the result, but in this case not so much.